# Mapping bidirectional OneToOne with single table column

Tags: java, hibernate, persistence, one-to-one

I'm having two entities:

```
@Entity
public class Device extends AbstractEntity {

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "item")
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private ItemOverview itemOverview;
}
```

And the entity ItemOverview:

```
@Entity
public class ItemOverview extends AbstractEntity {

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "item_id")
    private Item item;
}
```

They both extend from `AbstractEntity` which has, amongst others, the following:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
protected Long id;
```

In the database, the only reference that exists between the two tables is `ItemOverview` having a column `item_id`. The table `Item` does not know about `ItemOverview` when looking at the database.

So, when I try to save new ItemOverview objects containing Item (which already exists!), the ItemOverview objects get saved succesfully. But when I try to do it again, effectively updating the ItemOverview object (without changing Item), it tries to INSERT the Item object rather than updating it (or skipping it alltogether). Why does this happen?

Comment: can you show code related to hibernate session and updating entity ?

Comment: Nothing special happens here. I just fetch and save the entities using JpaRepository.

Comment: Hibernate entity looks fine,while updating entity you first get it from Database update it with new values and update it in hibernate session, isn't it ? or this should be your flow.

Comment: @Darshit You are actually right.. I mess up somewhere in my updating code, trying to save a copied (not fetched by Hibernate) instance instead. No wonder it updates. Thank you for putting me in the right direction! If you post this as an answer I can accept that.

Comment: That's why it was inserting new record instead of updating current because that object was not attached with hibernate session.
Feeling glad that I can help you :)